# Where is WebApiConfig in Web API 2 core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm following [this](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/) tutorial in attempts to expose an odata endpoint for a static collection.

**Where should this be configured?**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "Demos";
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
        builder.EntitySet<Person>("People");
        builder.EntitySet<Trip>("Trips");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

Here is the current structure:

[image]

**Where can I configure the MapOdataEndPoint and create the model builder?**

Comment: You seem to be mixing up versions. asp.net core is the new rewritten version of web api. WebAPIConfig was from the previous version of asp.net. You are going to have to clarify exactly which version you are trying to use.

Comment: i need to use odata v4 with asp.net core v2

Comment: You are following a tutorial for Web API 2, which is entirely different from ASP.NET Core MVC (which is what your project looks like). The officially supported OData library for ASP.NET Core is [this one](https://github.com/OData/odata.net).

Comment: i am an idiot..

Comment: @FedericoDipuma i dont see anything there for core.

Comment: From what I can see that library (which is the only one targeting .NET Standard) is the only one supported in .NET Core. It is not an out-of-the-box implementation on top of MVC, it is only the core library. Full support is [still uncertain](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1014).